# Google search for address using python

Tags: python

How to get the address of any hotel,restaurant,place,mall using python?
I have already used geopy package which works for some specific places but not for all.Is there any other way out.

Comment: 5 seconds in google yields : http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Google has geocoding services but they pass data using JSON responses. You will have to parse the JSON schema.

```
import requests
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
p = {'address:' 'New York'}
r = requests.get(url, params=p).json()
results = r['results']
```

results will hold your location. You simply have to retrieve what's needed. Hope that helps.

If there are any problems let me know